# update each td value of a table in ajax success

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a check box on page on click of it  i want to update each td element in ajax success.
e.g: i have 6 rows in a table on each row am sending an ajax call and on that current row only i want to update td element.

```
var val1 = [];
 $(".checkbox").change(function () {
        debugger;

        var val3 = $("#RID").val();
        var val4 = $("#MID").val();

        $('#subList input:checked').each(function () {
            val1.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });


        $("#tblOptions > tbody > tr").each(function () {
            debugger;
            var tr = $("#tblOptions > tbody > tr")
            var val2 = $(this).find('input:hidden')[0].value
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Value/ValidateCheck",
                data: { param1: val1, param2: val2, param3: val3, param4: val4 },
                datatype: "json",
                traditional: true,

                success: function (data) {
                  //here i want to update the current td element 

                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Html table:

```
@model Models.Checklist
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered mb-lg " id="tblOptions">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbodyOP">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Checklist.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Checklist[i].val1, new { @class = "Column1" })                
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Checklist[i].val2, new { @class = "form-control deletecls", required = "required" })</td>
                <td></td> //Blank td where value need to be added
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Checklist[i].val3, new { @class = "form-control deletecls", required = "required" })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please don't add images that is irrelevant, please include your table's HTML

Comment: i have added the html table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options. The easiest one to implement without much work, is to find the right elements with jquery, and that would be something around this:

```
$(".checkbox").change(function () {
    debugger;

    var val3 = $("#RID").val();
    var val4 = $("#MID").val();

    $('#subList input:checked').each(function () {
        val1.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });

    var rowTds = $(this.closest("tr")).find("td"); //to find all the checkboxe's row tds
    rowTds.each(function () {          
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Value/ValidateCheck",
            data: { param1: val1, param2: val2, param3: val3, param4: val4 },
            datatype: "json",
            traditional: true,

            success: function (data) {
             $(this).text(data); //if you only want to update the text of the tds
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside success function you can use the following to go through every td of a single row:

```
 var i=0;
 val1 = "ciao";
 val2 = "ciao2";
 val3 = "ciao3";
 val4 = "ciao4";
 var arr = [val1, val2, val3, val4];
 $(this).find('td').each (function() {
     $(this).html(arr[i]); 
     i++;
 });
```

Change val1-4 with your new data. Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dva0x7zn/8/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, above example update each and every record. my scenario is  column first has a hidden value am passing that in ajax and want to update value in second column first row than second row has hidden value am passing that in ajax and want to update the td in second row and so on...

Comment: Substitute  $(this).find('td').each (function()  with the following:

$( this ).find( "td:eq( 1 )").html("NewUpdate"));

It will update second column of each row with NewUpdate vaule.